# Python: Argparse does not parse long text argument

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm writing a new CLI with pyton and using cmd and argparse libraries. When i set a argument and call it with a long text option it does not recognize it was a text and throws an exception.

Here is how i use arguments:

```
WACP:~ cli$ add -t group -n NameForNewGroup -desc 'Description for new group' -c 2
```

Response is:

```
unrecognized arguments: - t   g r o u p   - n   N a m e F o r N e w G r o u p   - d e s c   ' D e s c r i p t i o n   f o r   n e w   g r o u p '   - c   2
```

Here how i add arguments:

```
self.parser.add_argument('-t', '--type',
                                 dest='type',
                                 help=Language.MSG_ADD_TYPE_HELP,
                                 action='store',
                                 default='device'
)
self.parser.add_argument('-c', '--config',
                                 dest='config',
                                 help=Language.MSG_ADD_GROUP_HELP,
                                 action='store',
                                 default=0
)
self.parser.add_argument('-n', '--name',
                                 dest='name',
                                 help=Language.MSG_ADD_NAME_HELP,
                                 action='store',
                                 default='New Device'
)
self.parser.add_argument('-desc', '--description',
                                 dest='description',
                                 help=Language.MSG_ADD_DESC_HELP,
                                 type=complex,
                                 action='store',
                                 default='Default description for device or group included in configuration values')
```

I looked argparse documentation and did not configure how it could be.

I have to handle this long text parsing and make it work.

Is there anyone has an idea to solve  that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.  Maybe you can produce a minimal test case?  What version of Python?  Are you sure you're using `argparse` and not `optparse`?  Are you calling `parse_args()` on the right object?  What's the output of `-h`?

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-t', '--type',
               dest='type')
p.add_argument('-c', '--config',
               dest='config')
p.add_argument('-n', '--name',
               dest='name')
p.add_argument('-desc', '--description',
               dest='description')
print(p.parse_args())
```

When run:

```
$ python test.py -t group -n NameForNewGroup -desc 'Description for new group' -c 2
Namespace(config='2', description='Description for new group', name='NameForNewGroup', type='group')
$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-t TYPE] [-c CONFIG] [-n NAME] [-desc DESCRIPTION]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t TYPE, --type TYPE
  -c CONFIG, --config CONFIG
  -n NAME, --name NAME
  -desc DESCRIPTION, --description DESCRIPTION
```

### Note

1. Normally, if you have short (e.g. `-t`) and long (e.g. `--type`) arguments, the short arguments should be one character each.  So `-desc` is a bit weird.
2. You don't want `type=complex`.  The `complex` type is used for complex numbers, such as `1+0.5j`.
3. The default action is `store`, so you can omit it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, this weird why it throws an exception i use almost same as you do, right? Only gave some other params that i need. I tried with your way and it works for me as well. But in app it doesn't. There may be some other issue(s) triggering that.

Comment: In that case, I don't have enough information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally You have to prefix longoptions with two hypens "--". Maybe this is the problem? Don't know if only "-" also works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `parse_args`?  The spacing in the response `- t   g r o u p   - n   N...` suggests that you have done `p.parse_args(list('-t group -n N...'))`, or its equivalent.  Each character is a separate argument string.

Or maybe you are doing `p.parse_args('-t group -n N ...')`.  For testing the call should be something like `p.parse_args(['-t','group','-n','N', ...])` (a list of strings).